# empty crossfilter dimension

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

When running the following code, the first console.log is returning the contents of the crossfilter instance, but the second console.log is return empty brackets.

Why isn't data getting into my crossfilter dimension?

```
var cf = require('./crossfilter.js');

var payments = cf([
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab", productIDs:["001"]},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:20:19Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab", productIDs:["001", "005"]},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:28:54Z", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa", productIDs:["004" ,"005"]}
]);
var paymentsByTotal = payments.dimension(function(d) { return d.total; });

console.log(JSON.stringify(payments.all()))
console.log(JSON.stringify(paymentsByTotal.filterAll()))
```

Comment: Because dimension.top(Infinity) will return your dimension data. dimension.filterAll() just clears filters on the dimension.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you.  Top(k) works and I will use it.  I have submitted an issue to the Crossfilter team, though, because their API reference says that filterAll "Clears any filters on this dimension, selecting all records and returning this dimension" and give the sample code/comment: paymentsByTotal.filterAll(); // selects all payments